# Change of Magento contacts page URL

Tags: magento

How can I change Magento contacts page URL from `/contacts` to `contact-us.html`?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 20):

1. In the *Catalog* menu click on *URL Rewrite Management*.
2. Click the *Add URL Rewrite* button.
3. Choose to add a *Custom* type.
4. Enter "contacts" for *ID Path* and *Target Path*.
5. Enter "contact-us.html" for the *Request Path*.
6. Click the *Save* button.

Comment: I tried to add rewrite step by step - still getting 404. What might cause the problem?

Comment: I cannot think of anything definite, it's usually reliable.  Perhaps you need to clear the cache, or maybe you accidentally got some of the fields mixed up.

Comment: As you said - probably I mixed up the fields. I've add rewrite once again and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Worked well for me. I couldn't figure out why it was still 404'ing until I re-read the answer - I was putting "contacts" into the Request Path and not the Target Path (as Magento lists the fields in the order of ID Path, Request Path, Target Path).

Answer (score 13):

The 'proper' way would be to create a small module similar to the below;

> app/etc/modules/Organisation_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Organisation_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Organisation_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and...

> app/code/local/Organisation/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Organisation_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Organisation_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mage_Contacts</module>
                    <frontName>contact-us.html</frontName>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Upload your files, clear your cache and you're good to go.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

Specifically must be

**New Url** in *ID Path* and *Target Path*.
**Old Url** in *Request Path*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the URL stub?

Comment: I,m a newbie to magento, so can you explain to me what might URL stub that be.