# Change of Magento contacts page URL on magento 2.1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento2.1

I think Magento 2.1 changed the way how to modify the url of contact page.
The old tutorials is not working anymore, like this: ([Change of Magento contacts page URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896028/change-of-magento-contacts-page-url)).

Maybe im doing something wrong too.

Can anyone help me?

I will appreciate any response.

[image: URL configuration]

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can create a static block and put contact block. After that create a category of contact and assign that static block in this category

Comment: I think it could work, but it is a long way to do a thing that should be simple. Do you know something different? thanks by your time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite the routes.xml file present in `vendor\magento\module-contact\etc\frontend\` folder

change from

```
<code>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="contact" frontName="contact">
            <module name="Magento_Contact" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>

</code>
```

to:

```
<code>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="YOUR_Choice" frontName="YOUR_Choice">
            <module name="Magento_Contact" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>

</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here you have to Add 2 URL Rewrite 
For example for login
1) 
    Request Path : customer/account/login
    Target Path : login
    Redirect Type : Permanent (301)

2 (another rewrite for same )

   Request Path : login
    Target Path :  customer/account/login
    Redirect Type : NO

Hope fully it will works.
In both url call perform same operations
```

Comment: I tryied your tutorial, but it does not work. Take in mind that i dont want to redirect the url, i want to alter the url. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use.htacess write following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
or you can do with admin panel also
```

or

1st->go to admin->marketing->seo&search->urlrewrite change url according to your requirements